# Sorting an Array with duplicates using Insertion sort

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort, code-complexity

```
package com.sort;

public class ArraySel {

    private Long[] a;
    private int nElems;

    public ArraySel(int max)
    {
        a = new Long[max];
        nElems = 0;
    }

    public void insert(long max)
    {
        a[nElems] = max;
        nElems++;
    }

    public void display()
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < nElems; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[j]+ "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void insertionSort()
    {
        int in , out, flag = 0;
        long temp;
        for(out = 1; out < nElems; out++)
        {
            temp = a[out];
            in = out;
            while(in > 0 && a[in - 1] >= temp )
            {
                if(a[in] == a[in - 1 ])
                {
                    flag++;
                    in--;
                }
                else
                {
                    a[in] = a[in-1];
                    in--;
                }
            }
            a[in] = temp;
        }
    }

}
```

This code takes an unsorted array and sorts it using Insertion Sort.
When duplicates are arranged together in unsorted array then due to multiple shifting complexity raises to `O(N^2)` , which i tried to make it `O(N)` by making sure no item moved more than once in case of duplicates arranged together.

But when duplicates are not arranged together complexity remains `O(N^2)`.
Can we make the complexiy `O(N)` in this case too ?

Comment: "When duplicates are arranged together in unsorted array then due to multiple shifting complexity raises to O(N2) , which i tried to make it O(N) by making sure no item moved more than once in case of duplicates arranged together." - If the elements in the input array are not sorted, the complexity will still be O(n^2), irrespective of  whether duplicates follow each other or not.. example - 5,2,2,1,6 will still have complexity of O(n^2)

Comment: Insertion sort time complexity is always O(N^2) if I'm not wrong

Comment: @Kartik_Koro - if the input array is sorted, then the best case complexity of insertion sort becomes O(n)

Comment: @TheLostMind I know, but we are talking about big O notation, i.e. upper bound right?

Comment: @Kartik_Koro yes.. The time complexity for a sorted array is O(n). Which means for a sorted array, the time cannot go beyond (someConstant * n). We are still setting the upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further information about the underlying data, the *best* [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) you can achieve with sorting algorithms is `O(n log n)` (*n* being the number of elements).

Sorting algorithms like insertion sort, bubble sort, selection sort, etc., all have a time complexity of `O(n²)` due to their double loops. In fact they sometimes tend to work better, when getting an already sorted list of elements. [Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) for example has a time complexity of `O(n)` for a completely sorted list.

There is nothing you can do to change the inherent time complexity of those algorithms. The only thing you can do is short-cutting the algorithm when finding pre-sorted regions in the incoming list.

Answer (score 2):

Complexity isn't given by the number of moves but by the number of operations overall, in this case comparisons as well.

Insertion sort is O(n^2) average complexity, you can't make it faster than that. In works in O(n) only in best case scenario, when the input string is already sorted (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).